# ClassLoader exception when running ant on windows with java 1.8

Tags: java, exception, ant

I ran into this issue when running ant on a windows system with java 1.8.60. This was working fine when running java 1.7.25. Even more interesting : it runs fine when executed on a mac?

I am kind of lost since there is not much pointing me towards a cause of this problem.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1448)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1433)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at sun.misc.MetaIndex.registerDirectory(MetaIndex.java:184)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Launcher.java:146)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Launcher.java:142)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader(Launcher.java:141)
        at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:71)
        at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:57)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1448)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1433)
```

Comment: What if you fall back to an earlier version of Java 8, say update 51?

Comment: I also tried 1.8.51 with the exact same result :(

Comment: Can you run any other Java program than ant?

Comment: ok hello world also fails - so it seems to be either a completely broken JVM install - or a some environment stuff interfering with the JVM

Comment: That is what I was expecting, yes. Time to get JavaRa and do some cleaning.

Comment: previously i was using an "embedded" version of java - using the system level java 8 install, works like a charm! thank you a lot for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure the JVM was installed properly?
We had the same problem when the JVM was installed via a repository (CVS) which converted some text-files from/to DOS/UNIX format.